# AspectJ - can't run the load time weaving example

Tags: java, aspectj

I am getting to know AspectJ, and I am working my way through some examples. However, when I run one of them, my run fails:

`$ java -cp /c/aspectj1.7/lib/aspectjrt.jar:/c/aspectj1.7/lib/aspectjweaver.jar:. -javaagent:aspectjweaver.jar   Simple
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : aspectjweaver.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument`

I am doing it in MinGW on windows, and I am sure that the jar is there. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, even though you use MinGW and unix paths in it, you still have to provide the path to the agent in the windows way remembering, however, that the backslash is an escape char in Unix, so you have to escape it with another back slash.

`$ java -javaagent:C:\\aspectj1.7\\lib\\aspectjweaver.jar   Simple
    execution(void Simple.count(int, int)) took 0ms
  execution(void Simple.countFast(int)) took 4ms
    execution(void Simple.count(int, int)) took 5021ms
  execution(void Simple.countSlow(int)) took 5021ms
execution(void Simple.main(String[])) took 5030ms`